# Why won't my code to move data from one worksheet to another work?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a workbook with two worksheets:

"MASTER" and "Submitted"

When the word in Column "P" on the "Master" sheet is changed from "PENDING" to "SUBMITTED" I want the row to be removed from the MASTER sheet and added to the last row of the SUBMITTED sheet.

I can save the Script with no errors, but when I change the cell to "SUBMITTED" from "PENDING" nothing happens...

```
function onEdit(event) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var r = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveRange();

  if(s.getName() == "MASTER" && r.getColumn() == 17 && r.getValue() == "SUBMITTED") {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("SUBMITTED");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
  }
}
```

Comment: you said you have two worksheets: "MASTER" and "Submitted" but in your code you use "SUBMITTED". Are you sure that this is not some sort of a syntax error?

Comment: Any error Logs in tools>executions?

Comment: Column P is 16 not 17

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const s=e.range.getSheet();
  if(s.getName()=="MASTER" && e.range.columnStart==16 && e.value=="SUBMITTED") {
    const ts=e.source.getSheetByName('SUBMITTED');
    s.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,s.getLastColumn()).moveTo(ts.getRange(ts.getLastRow()+1,1));
    s.deleteRow(e.range.rowStart);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that:

- the names of the tabs are: *MASTER* and *SUBMITTED*,
- cells in column P need to be edited to the value: *SUBMITTED*,
- P column is **16** and not 17.

This will work:

```
function onEdit(e) {

  const row = e.range.getRow();
  const col = e.range.getColumn();
  const s = e.source.getSheetByName("MASTER")
  const as = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  const targetSheet = e.source.getSheetByName("SUBMITTED");

  if(as.getName() == "MASTER" && col == 16 && as.getRange(row,col).getValue() == "SUBMITTED") {  
        targetSheet.appendRow(s.getRange(row, 1, 1, s.getLastColumn()).getValues().flat([1]));     
        s.deleteRow(row);
  }
}
```